# Silverlight 4 C# - How to get value of SelectedItem from a listbox?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a string variable that I'm trying to grab the text of the SelectedItem from a listbox when I click on the item.

I'd think that:

```
String txt = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

would work, but it only converts the type of the item to a string. For instance, if the item that I clicked on says "howdy" I want the string to have "howdy" in it.

I'm sure it's an incredibly simple solution, but I'm rather stumped!

Thanks in advance!

-Sootah

Comment: I thought SelectedItem should do the job, maybe it does depend on how it is binding in XAML. What happens when you try to grab `SelectedValue` instead? If that doesn't work - pls post some code

Comment: In the XAML I just manually declared the items of the listbox for the moment, like so: <ListBoxItem Content="Word1" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. Here's what I did:

```
ListBoxItem selected = listBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;

MessageBox.Show(selected.Content.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

```
String txt = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: I've tried that as well. It returns "System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem" instead of the text.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the instance name of the ListBox? (post some more code, especially the part where xaml is declared for the listbox)